# javascript autocompletion for DSL. (e.g.: SQL)

Tags: javascript

I want to give the user a web-page where he can type some simple SQL.

select * from myTable.

What I would like is to have the autocompletion area to help typing:

- sel
- [selECT]
- select * f
- [select * fROM]
- select * from
- [select * fROM column1]
- [select * fROM column2]
- ...

Anybody can suggest if there is a nice open source library for this ?

I am not really interested in the SQL (I will have to parse a DSL)
I am more interested on a powerful autocompletion text area widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have left this unanswered for a while.
I am afraid it's fair to saythat there is not an autocompletion widget as described in my question.

Answer (score -2):

This is a good jQuery auto-completion widget:

- [jQuery/Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete)

Or, if you're more apt to hack something together yourself, Ordered list has an excellent write-up using a string matching algorithm ported from the excellent Quicksilver app (for the mac) :

- [Live Search with Quicksilver Style](http://orderedlist.com/blog/articles/live-search-with-quicksilver-style/)